# Java ClassDefFoundError & NoClassFoundException

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a small 2D game with Notepad++ and Java JDK 7. I don't want to use a IDE like Eclipse so my java files and classes are in my **C:\Users\Jeremy\Documents\ZombieSurvival** directory. To compile and run my code i use the npexec plugin from notepad++ and execute the commands :

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javac Game.java** (compiling)

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java Game** (running)

**EVERYTHING** was working until I started to code my TileMap class. If I use this class a ClassNotFoundError and NoClassDefFoundException pop up. It's pretty curious because in another game of me java shows the same error in my Map class so is the reason for the mistake my TileMap class? Like I said without using this class the program runs perfectly! Any ideas?

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;


public class TileMap {

private int[][] map;
private int mapWidth;
private int mapHeight;
private int tileSize;

private BufferedImage image;
private Graphics2D g;

public TileMap(String file, int tileSize) {
    this.tileSize = tileSize;
    loadMap(new File(file));
}

public void update() {

}

public void render(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}

private void loadMap(File file) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    mapWidth = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    mapHeight = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    map = new int[mapHeight][mapWidth];

    image = new BufferedImage(mapWidth, mapHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

    for(int col = 0; col < mapHeight; col ++) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");

        for(int row = 0; row < mapWidth; row++) {
            map[col][row] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[row]);
        }
    }
}

private void drawMap() {
    for(int col = 0; col < mapHeight; col ++) {
        for(int row = 0; row < mapWidth; row++) {
            int block = map[col][row];
            if(block == 1) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

            g.fillRect(row * tileSize, col * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Are you making sure to compile your TileMap.java?  You'll need to make sure its .class file is on the classpath, too.

Comment: Please show the javac cmd for the other class and the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access other (non-JRE) classes from your class, you need to explicitly tell the JVM where the class files are located using the `classpath` option. Use this to run your app (assuming the working directory is `C:\Users\Jeremy\Documents\ZombieSurvival`):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java -classpath "." Game
```

Comment: thanks for replying! i tried to run the program with that code but nothing changed :/

Comment: EDIT: i forgot try catch for the FileReader, for some reason cmd showed me errors where npexec says that everything is correct

Comment: @AvarionDE: Yep, so it didn't create the class file when you compiled TileMap. Once TileMap compiles successfully (and you recompile Game), the above command will run Game without problem.